# Unity 3D : how to actual bottom point of a Bounds?

Tags: unity-game-engine

[image]

As above image, small red box is the Bound's 'min' point, and magenta box is bound's 'max' point.

but i need to know actual bottom point of these cars in programmatically.

for example, in above case, a points which around of right side of front bumper of each cars.

how do i know that?

Answer (score 1):

Easiest and most accurate way would be to attach an empty game object on the prefab. You can then manually place it exactly where it should be and easily retrieve the position if you need it.

Comment: Exactly. Attach a "marker" object.  (In Unity, simply an empty GameObject.) You're done.